# TensorFlow FIFOQueue not FIFO?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am enqueuing items in a particular order onto a TensorFlow [`FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue) and expecting to be able to dequeue them in the same order but this is not the behaviour I am observing.

Running the following stand-alone code demonstrates the approach and behaviour. This has been run on Python 2.7 (but might work in Python 3) with TensorFlow 1.1.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import math
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import queue_runner
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

row_count, column_count = 7, 5
batch_size, step_size = 3, 2

# Create some random data
data = numpy.arange(row_count * column_count).reshape(
    (row_count, column_count))
print(data)

batch_count = int(math.ceil(row_count / batch_size))
step_count = int(math.ceil(column_count / step_size))
print(batch_count, step_count)

slices = tf.train.slice_input_producer([data], num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
batch = tf.train.batch(slices, batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

queue = tf.FIFOQueue(32, dtypes=[batch.dtype])
enqueue_ops = []
dependency = None

for step_index in range(step_count):
    step = tf.strided_slice(
        batch, [0, step_index * step_size],
        [tf.shape(batch)[0], (step_index + 1) * step_size])

    if dependency is None:
        dependency = step
    else:
        step = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([dependency], step)

    enqueue_ops.append(queue.enqueue(step))

queue_runner.add_queue_runner(queue_runner.QueueRunner(
    queue=queue, enqueue_ops=[tf.group(*enqueue_ops)]))
step = queue.dequeue()

supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor()

with supervisor.managed_session() as session:
    for batch_index in range(batch_count):
        for step_index in range(step_count):
            print("Batch %d, step %d" % (batch_index, step_index))
            print(session.run(step))
```

The expected output is

```
Batch 0, step 0
[[ 0  1]
 [ 5  6]
 [10 11]]
Batch 0, step 1
[[ 2  3]
 [ 7  8]
 [12 13]]
Batch 0, step 2
[[ 4]
 [ 9]
 [14]]
Batch 1, step 0
[[15 16]
 [20 21]
 [25 26]]
Batch 1, step 1
[[17 18]
 [22 23]
 [27 28]]
Batch 1, step 2
[[19]
 [24]
 [29]]
Batch 2, step 0
[[30 31]]
Batch 2, step 1
[[32 33]]
Batch 2, step 2
[[34]]
```

The actual output is

```
Batch 0, step 0
[[ 0  1]
 [ 5  6]
 [10 11]]
Batch 0, step 1
[[ 4]
 [ 9]
 [14]]
Batch 0, step 2
[[ 2  3]
 [ 7  8]
 [12 13]]
Batch 1, step 0
[[15 16]
 [20 21]
 [25 26]]
Batch 1, step 1
[[19]
 [24]
 [29]]
Batch 1, step 2
[[17 18]
 [22 23]
 [27 28]]
Batch 2, step 0
[[30 31]]
Batch 2, step 1
[[32 33]]
Batch 2, step 2
[[34]]
```

Note that the order of the steps in batches 0 and 1 are incorrect. I have been unable to determine what the order of the steps is. It appears the batches are always in order but the steps within each batch come out in "random" order: it appears deterministic, but not FIFO.

I have tried with and without the explicit dependency declarations as used in the code above. I have tried setting the queue capacity to 1. I have tried setting `enqueue_ops=enqueue_ops` instead of using `tf.group` but none of these changes helped and the final one caused very strange output.

Maybe [`tf.group`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) somehow ignores dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops.with_dependencies` isn't working as I thought, or I was using it incorrectly. If I switch to to using `tf.control_dependencies` instead, I get the behaviour I need:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import math
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training import queue_runner

row_count, column_count = 7, 5
batch_size, step_size = 3, 2

# Create some random data
data = numpy.arange(row_count * column_count).reshape(
    (row_count, column_count))
print(data)

batch_count = int(math.ceil(row_count / batch_size))
step_count = int(math.ceil(column_count / step_size))
print(batch_count, step_count)

slices = tf.train.slice_input_producer([data], num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
batch = tf.train.batch(slices, batch_size, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

queue = tf.FIFOQueue(32, dtypes=[batch.dtype])
enqueue_ops = []
dependency = None

for step_index in range(step_count):
    step = tf.strided_slice(
        batch, [0, step_index * step_size],
        [tf.shape(batch)[0], (step_index + 1) * step_size])

    if dependency is None:
        dependency = queue.enqueue(step)
    else:
        with tf.control_dependencies([dependency]):
            step = queue.enqueue(step)
            dependency = step

    enqueue_ops.append(step)

queue_runner.add_queue_runner(queue_runner.QueueRunner(
    queue=queue, enqueue_ops=[tf.group(*enqueue_ops)]))
step = queue.dequeue()

supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor()

with supervisor.managed_session() as session:
    for batch_index in range(batch_count):
        for step_index in range(step_count):
            print("Batch %d, step %d" % (batch_index, step_index))
            print(session.run(step))
```

This answer was motivated by the [answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244929/127480).