# TensorFlow tf.group ignoring dependencies?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following on from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244275/tensorflow-fifoqueue-not-fifo), it seems `tf.group` is indeed ignoring dependencies. Here's a simple stand-alone example (I have run it on Python 2.7 with TensorFlow 1.1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

xs = [tf.constant(x) for x in range(10)]
xs = [tf.Print(x, [x]) for x in xs]
dependency = None
dxs = []

for x in xs:
    if dependency is None:
        dependency = x
    else:
        dependency = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([dependency], x)

    dxs.append(dependency)

print_all_op = tf.group(*dxs)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(print_all_op)
```

Expected output:

```
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961221: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [0]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961236: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [1]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961255: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [2]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961237: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [3]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961262: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [4]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961263: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [5]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961268: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [6]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961272: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [7]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961274: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [8]
2017-05-29 15:11:53.961221: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [9]
```

Actual output (different each time the code is run):

```
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279655: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [0]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279655: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [9]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279697: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [3]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279660: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [1]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279711: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [8]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279713: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [4]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279723: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [5]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279663: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [2]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279724: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [7]
2017-05-29 15:16:26.279728: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] [6]
```

There's nothing in the [`tf.group`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/group) documentation to indicate why dependencies are ignored.

Is there an alternative to `tf.group` that does consider dependencies?

Switching to use `tf.control_dependencies` instead of `tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops.with_dependencies` doesn't help:

```
import tensorflow as tf

xs = [tf.constant(x) for x in range(10)]
xs = [tf.Print(x, [x]) for x in xs]
dependency = None
dxs = []

for x in xs:
    if dependency is None:
        dependency = x
    else:
        with tf.control_dependencies([dependency]):
            dependency = x

    dxs.append(dependency)

print_all_op = tf.group(*dxs)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(print_all_op)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the initial code creates dependencies between dummy identity ops implicitly created by `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies` and not the actual `tf.Print` ops. Tensorflow seems to only ensure that the ops in the dependency list have been already executed but the order of other preceding ops is not fixed. In the above example, the dependencies are created on the dummy identity ops created by `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies`:

```
    dependency = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([dependency], x)
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
        with tf.control_dependencies([dependency]):
            dependency = tf.identity(x)
```

Thus, the dependencies here are created between the `tf.identity` ops and not the `tf.Print` ops. The `tf.Print` ops can be run in any order, the strict ordering is only on the `tf.identity` ops. I don't think it is possible to achieve the desired behavior with `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies`. Instead one has to use `with tf.control_dependencies` instead (as already suggested by the op):

```
xs = [tf.constant(x) for x in range(10)]
dependency = None
dxs = []

for x in xs:
    if dependency is None:
        dependency = tf.Print(x, [x])
    else:
        with tf.control_dependencies([dependency]):
            dependency = tf.Print(x, [x])

    dxs.append(dependency)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tf.control_dependencies` correctly does solve this problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf

xs = [tf.constant(x) for x in range(10)]
dependency = None
dxs = []

for x in xs:
    if dependency is None:
        dependency = tf.Print(x, [x])
    else:
        with tf.control_dependencies([dependency]):
            dependency = tf.Print(x, [x])

    dxs.append(dependency)

print_all_op = tf.group(*dxs)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(print_all_op)
```

Note that the `Print` operation needs to be created within the `tf.control_dependencies` context manager.

I am still unclear why the `control_flow_ops.with_dependencies` version fails.